# Mocking aws-sdk-java 2.0

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I'm trying to test my AWS Lambda function but I can't figure out how to mock the 2.0 SDK with Mockito. Basically, all I want is to create a couple DBSnapshot mocks and set a bit of test information on them (snapshot name and creation time would be enough for my purposes).

If I make a new DBSnapshot with the 'new' operator, I can't seem to set any parameters on it, or even mock a builder with a request to create one.

In the 1.0 SDK, I could mock a DBSnapshot and set various ".withBlah' params like below:

```
DBSnapshot testSnapshot = new DBSnapshot().withSnapshotCreateTime("2020-01-01")[...]
```

but it doesn't seem possible here since the 2.0 rewrite to force everything through a builder, and I'm not sure how to mock it now. Googling hasn't turned up any code examples for the 2.0 SDK/RDS in particular.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```java
DBSnapshot testSnapshot = DBSnapshot
    .builder()
    .snapshotCreateTime(Instant.now())
    .build();
```

Comment: If I wanted to truly mock it though, I guess I would first need to mock the builder somehow? I know this is in line with the example I gave above, but it still represents actually reaching out to the AWS API.

Comment: @Rome_Leader, no need to mocking the builder in order to mock its subject. Just mock the `DBSnapshot`. It's a final class, so there may be some nuances in doing so. It really depends on the mocking framework you use. It's pretty easy to do in mockito: [Mock Final Classes and Methods with Mockito](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final#final-class).